# Customize the Container Login Page

Tags: java, jsf-2

I use container managed security in my JSF app so I have a login page
with below default setup.

Now in the login page, I wanted to add a button beside the login button to allow 
the user to register.

But how do I forward it to my register.xhtml page from my register button?  I tried it with this code:

```
<form method="post" action="j_security_check">
    <div id="login-content">
        <p>Login to access secure pages:</p>
        <p:panelGrid columns="2">
            <h:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Username" />
            <input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username" />

            <h:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password" />
            <input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password" />

            <f:facet name="footer">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
                <input type="button" name="register" 
                    value="#{request.contextPath}/pages/public/register.xhtml" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:panelGrid>
    </div>
</form>
```

I tried changing also the form to h:form so that I could use the p:commandButton but as I notice,
my login page is not working and nothing is happening when I click the submit button.

How to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: Why do you need to have both the login process and register buttons in the same form? Put your login form in a regular html `<form/>` and stick the registration in a JSF `<h:form/>` and you can redirect to your registration page using a regular `<h:commandButton/>`. You just style them to sit next to each other. That OK by you?

Comment: Looks like this is the option that I have for now.. I will just leave the question for some time.. maybe somebody has some other ideas..Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `<h:button>` or `<p:button>` to create a GET button.

```html
<h:button value="register" outcome="/pages/public/register.xhtml" />
```